# WinEdt compatibility issues with TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker, winedt

I have written a manuscript in TeXMaker, and my advisor has requested the LaTeX file for edits. He has WinEdt (I am not sure which version). He is not able to compile and run my LateX file. I don't know what he has or has not tried.

What could be the source of the problem? Are there some known compatibility issues between the two programs? As far as I know, the packages could be the problem, but I don't know which ones.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{resizegather}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}
```

TITLE, AUTHORS, AFFILIATIONS

```
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}
\def\mathclap#1{\text{\hbox to 0pt{\hss$\mathsurround=0pt#1$\hss}}}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{48}
\begin{document}
```

MANUSCRIPT

```
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A priori*, the only incompatibility between WinEdt and TeXmaker, would com from an old version of WinEdt ($<7$) because of utf8 encoding. If so, your advisor should update WinEdt to last version (9).

However, it may happen he/she has not all the packages you load installed on his system. Also, it is known that `breqn`may have conflicts with other math packages.

Comment aside, it's needless to define `\mathclap` as it's already defined by `mathtools` which you should load in the place of `amsmath` (it's a particularly useful extension of the latter)